# Integrated Authorization/Authentication in Adobe Flash and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, authentication

I'd like to display live-stream content to users based on their permission levels.
The permissions are set in an ASP.NET MVC web application, And if the user is not authenticated *and* authorized, he/she should not be able to view the stream even if they have the swf address directly.

Is there any way that I can inform my flash project about current user's permission levels that cannot be tampered in client-side, and decide how to react in flash project?

P.S. Unfortunately, silverlight is not an option for me unless it's impossible in flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit speculative, and might have been better as a comment, but I wanted to include a couple of long links. I'll delete if it turns out to be wildly wrong:

Can't you just let the MVC authorization framework take care of this, by returning the stream content via code which is protected with a [Principal Permission](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/04/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Adding-Authorization-Rules-to-Business-and-Data-Layers-using-PrincipalPermissionAttributes.aspx) attribute, or with `Web.Config` role-based protection on the folder? Any request from the Flash player within a browser ought to include the current [Asp.Net encrypted cookie](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443), so I think you can just let the browser take care of this.

Comment: Based on your reply, I'll probably write and HTTP handler which serves .swf files and checks user's permissions first.

Comment: Yes, that's more elegant. You could always pass the Asp.Net cookie in to the Flash app and then have it relay the (encrypted) cookie, but the browser is doing this for you in any case, so it seems unnecessary to duplicate the effort. Hope it works out.